# WPF Binding DataContext in class

Tags: wpf, binding, resharper

I'm doing something similar to this : https://www.wpf-tutorial.com/data-binding/using-the-datacontext/.
I write `this.DataContext = this;`
in the cs file after the `InitialieComponents()`, and in the cs.xaml file I write `Command = "{Binding BackCommand}"` for a button.
But the resharper gives me an error: `Cannot resolve symbol ”BackCommand“ due to unknown DataContext` and the binding does not work.
Only If I do something like this it works: `Command = "{Binding BackCommand, elementName = root}"` and set the Name of the root xml(My class) to "root".

I dont understand why and how to fix this.. (Since I have seen instances where it worked just fine like in the url)

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You could add a DesignerDataContext to your XAML like:

```
<Window ...
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    d:DataContext="{d:DesignInstance Type=local:MyWindow, IsDesignTimeCreatable=False}"
 >
```

This makes tools aware of the type of the DataContext.

Side note: I would recommend using the MVVM pattern and using a separate ViewModel class as DataContext.